# svelte:component not displaying anything

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm trying to achieve a cde like in this repl:
https://svelte.dev/repl/16b375da9b39417dae837b5006799cb4?version=3.25.0

But I get an empty `<div id="#printable"></div>` tab on my page

```
<script>    
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let Home;
    onMount(async () => {
        console.log('loading home ', doc.templateId)
        switch (doc.templateId) {
            case '1':
                Home = await (import( '$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte')).default;
            case '2':
            case '3':
            default:
                Home = await (import( '$lib/template/_expert/Home.svelte')).default;
        }
        console.log(' home loaded ', doc.templateId)
    });
</script>

<div class='flex flex-col xl:flex-row'>
    <ResumeButtons {data} />

    <div class='flex flex-grow flex-row-reverse mt-4'>
        <!--        //used to balance the growth of the buttons panel-->
    </div>

    <div id='printable' class='flex-none'>
        <svelte:component this={Home} doc={doc} on:modified={documentModified}/>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my console, I can see the component was loaded:

```
loading home  2
 home loaded  2
```

I don't have any idea how I could debug what's going wrong

Just to validate the problem is not from the import path. If I import both templates, then write my code like follows, it works

```
import Expert from '$lib/template/_expert/Home.svelte';
import Artist from '$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte';
//...
//then use it directly without await
//...

    switch (doc.templateId) {
        case '1':
            Home = Artist;
            break
        case '2':
        case '3':
        default:
            Home = Expert;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't the parentheses at the imports wrong? Would expect:

```js
(await import('$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte')).default
// or
await import('$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte').then(m => m.default)
```

Comment: Tried Home = (await (import('$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte')).default) doesn't work, I can't use the then syntax here

Comment: You can always use `then`, you only *cannot* use `await` outside of `async` functions.

Comment: (There was a stray closing parenthesis in the first statement which I have removed now)

Comment: I mean, it would uselessly be a hard to read code (using then syntax)

Ok you're right: (await import( '$lib/template/_artist/Home.svelte')).default worked

Comment: Thank you!, 

Now I realize, I'd like the template to be loaded in SSR. Do you know how to do that?:

As it is now, the page loads without a template, then onMount() is called client side to check how to display the data.

Comment: I've put a default template to get it at least to show something: let Home = Expert;
But ideally it would show the right template

Comment: Regarding syntax, I prefer using `then` for cases like this, easier to track than parentheses that are far apart; but it's just personal preference. For SSR you might be able to just extract the function from `onMount` into a named function that returns a component type and use something like `{#await loadTemplate() then Home}` (haven't tested whether that executes on the server though).